# How can CMake be used to generate Makefiles with personalized commands?

Tags: makefile, project, cmake, tar

I like to keep my Makefiles flexible and multifunctional. One of the tasks I usually add to `make` command is `tar`, for example the following instruction does the job:

```
tar:
    tar -cvf $(PROGNAME).tar $(SRCS) Makefile
```

My question is: **How can CMake be used to generate personalized commands like `tar`?**
I would like to see some code samples.
For the full functionality it would be useful to create project's components and be able to use them as parameters.
(*Exempli gratia*: archive only header files or some specific library).

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal translation of your tar example would be:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(tar
    tar -cvf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROGNAME}.tar ${SRCS} Makefile
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

This adds a new target "tar" that always executes the given command whenever it is requested as a command line target, i.e. whenever you run `make tar` it will create a new tar file. The `WORKING_DIRECTORY` argument will ensure that the source files are taken from the source directory, while CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR ensures the output goes in the current build directory.

A slightly better iteration would be to replace `tar` with `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar`, as this doesn't depend on the command line `tar` program being available. So something like this would tar up all the header files when you run `make tar`:

```
SET(HEADER_FILES my.h another.h)
SET(PROGNAME myprog)
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(tar ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar -czvf
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROGNAME}.tar.gz ${HEADER_FILES}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

An even better iteration would be to use the CPack features to create source or binary tar files, but that's quite a bit more work and may not be what you need anyway.

Comment: Could not be explained better! Thank you!

Comment: By the way, why would I want to backup `Makefile` when you use **CMake**? =)

Comment: Why indeed! Maybe a wrapper Makefile that just had "mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS)"?